# Paperclip: integration with mailboxer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, attachment

I'm using [mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer) gem and I don't know how to use it with Paperclip (Message Class).

Using Paperclip with a User class is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture
end
```

How can I add has_attached_file to the Message class (there is no message.rb in models)?

Thank you.

Comment: the gem is meant to send messages inside a web app. If you parse the messages you could add html thus display pictures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but message should have any kind of file as attachment (jpg, pdf, ...). So `Message` class should have `has_mattached_file :document`. But the problem is how to do that considering that there is no message.rb in models folder.

Comment: actually, there are attachments! but with carrierwave, see: https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/master/app/models/message.rb#L13

Comment: Note:  the above link doesn't work, use instead:  https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/4b2681c1790b823f7b493fb00b41e9899bb90ebe/app/models/message.rb#L13

Comment: Or, more to the point, look in message.rb for the line that reads `mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

- use the built-in attachment made with carrierwave ([source](http://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/master/app/models/message.rb#L13))
- monkey patch the `Message` model:

in an initializer do:

```
Message.class_eval do

  #your paperclip code goes here

end
```

And don't forget [migrations](http://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/master/db/migrate/%E2%80%A6)!

Comment: I added this to an initializer file:
`Message.class_eval do
  attr_accessible :document
  has_attached_file :document
end`

and did the migrations but I get `undefined method 'document_file_name'` when I run `Message.first.document`

Comment: here is my schema.rb messages table content after migrations:
  `create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    .....
    .....
    t.string   "document_file_name"
    t.string   "document_content_type"
    t.integer  "document_file_size"
    t.datetime "document_updated_at"
  end` so the `document_file_name` is present in messages table.

Comment: ok it's sheer logic: `Message` is a STI, the root model is `Notification`. You should do like here: https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/master/db/migrate/20111204163911_add_attachments.rb

Comment: You're right, it works. I run the migration for notifications table and did Notification.class_eval instead of Message.class_eval and it's working now. Can you add an answer so that I accept it.

Comment: no need to class_eval notification, the current answer is fine

Comment: @apneadiving, can you update your answer, the "source" link you give is wrong.  I made a comment on the question (saying "the above link doesn't work ...") with corrected info.

Comment: Also, that "migrations" link fails.  This will work: https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/4b2681c1790b823f7b493fb00b41e9899bb90ebe/db/migrate/20111204163911_add_attachments.rb

Comment: Or ... well, in the newer version all migrations have been squished into one.  Here is the current migrations file as of Dec 2013:  https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/master/db/migrate/20110511145103_create_mailboxer.rb