# Adding belongs to relationship to Ruby Gem Mailboxer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

I am building an e-com application and would like to implement something like a messaging system. In the application, all conversation will be related to either a `Product` model or an `Order` model. In that case, I would like to store the relating object (type + id, I supposed) to the `Conversation` object.

To add the fields, of course I can generate and run a migration, however, since the Model and Controller are included within the gem, how can I declare the relationship? (`belongs_to :linking_object, :polymorphic`) and the controller? Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although rewriting a custom Conversation system will be the best long-term solution providing the customization requirement (Like linking with other models for instance), to save some time at the moment I have implement the link with a `ConversationLink` Model. I hope it would be useful for anyone in the future who are at my position.

Model: `conversation_link.rb`

```
class ConversationLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :linkingObject, polymorphic: true
end
```

then in each models I target to link with the `conversation`, I just add:

```
has_many :conversation_link, as: :linkingObject
```

This will only allow you to get the related conversation from the linking object, but the coding for reverse linking can be done via functions defined in a Module.

This is not a perfect solution, but at least I do not need to monkey patch the gem...

Answer (score 4):

I ended up customizing the Mailboxer gem to allow for a `conversationable` object to be attached to a conversation.

In `models/mailboxer/conversation.rb`

```
belongs_to :conversationable, polymorphic: true
```

Add the migration to make polymorphic associations work:

```
add_column :mailboxer_conversations, :conversationable_id, :integer
add_column :mailboxer_conversations, :conversationable_type, :string
```

In `lib/mailboxer/models/messageable.rb` you add the `conversationable_object` to the parameters for `send_message`:

```
def send_message(recipients, msg_body, subject, sanitize_text=true, attachment=nil, message_timestamp = Time.now, conversationable_object=nil)
  convo = Mailboxer::ConversationBuilder.new({
    :subject    => subject,
    :conversationable => conversationable_object,
    :created_at => message_timestamp,
    :updated_at => message_timestamp
  }).build

  message = Mailboxer::MessageBuilder.new({
    :sender       => self,
    :conversation => convo,
    :recipients   => recipients,
    :body         => msg_body,
    :subject      => subject,
    :attachment   => attachment,
    :created_at   => message_timestamp,
    :updated_at   => message_timestamp
  }).build

  message.deliver false, sanitize_text
end
```

Then you can have conversations around objects:

```
class Pizza < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversations, as: :conversationable, class_name: "::Mailboxer::Conversation"    
  ...
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversations, as: :conversationable, class_name: "::Mailboxer::Conversation"    
  ...
end
```

Assuming you have some users set up to message each other

```
bob = User.find(1)
joe = User.find(2)
pizza = Pizza.create(:name => "Bacon and Garlic")

bob.send_message(joe, "My Favorite", "Let's eat this", true, nil, Time.now, pizza)
```

Now inside your Message View you can refer to the object:

```
Pizza Name: <%= @message.conversation.conversationable.name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The gem automatically take care of this for you, as they have built a solution that any model in your own domain logic can act as a messagble object.

Simply declaring

```
acts_as_messagable
```

In your Order or Product model will accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @TheIrishGuy, thanks for your reply. However, the `acts_as_messageable` only allow the gem to know which object can be `sender` and `receiver` of the gem. What the app need is attaching a `product` or `order` to the conversation but the sender and receiver are still Users

Comment: Ok, what you'll want to do than is create a concern with your custom logic. Than monkey patch the conversations class to include that concern.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use something like:

```
form_helper :products
```

and add those fields to the message form

but mailboxer comes with attachment functionality(carrierwave) included

this might help if you need something like attachments in your messages:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12199364/1230075

Comment: Hi @Franklin-De-Los-Santos, thanks for your reply. What I need is to relate a conversation with an model object so that's slightly different. I am thinking if there are no more straight forward options than monkey patching the gem, I would prefer to add another model which is completely separated with the gem instead...