# Passing object with Mailboxer notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, mailboxer

I'm trying to send a notification to a user with Mailboxer, and I need to pass an object along which will affect how the notification is displayed in my navbar's notification dropdown.

```
@recipient.notify("#{current_user.name} needs you to review his help with: #{@offer.title}", "#{@message}", @offer)
```

The last argument is where I'm trying to pass the object, `@offer`.

This is the Mailboxer method which I'm trying to use:

```
 def notify(subject,body,obj = nil,sanitize_text=true,notification_code=nil,send_mail=true)
    Mailboxer::Notification.notify_all([self],subject,body,obj,sanitize_text,notification_code,send_mail)
  end
```

It calls this `notify_all` method:

```
def notify_all(recipients, subject, body, obj = nil, sanitize_text = true, notification_code=nil, send_mail=true)
  notification = Mailboxer::NotificationBuilder.new({
    :recipients        => recipients,
    :subject           => subject,
    :body              => body,
    :notified_object   => obj,
    :notification_code => notification_code
  }).build

  notification.deliver sanitize_text, send_mail
end
```

When I try to access object with this: `<%= notification.object_id %>`, I get a long number like `205981093`. And I get an error if I try to access one of the `offer` object's fields with this: `<%= notification.object_id.title %>`

```
`undefined method `title' for 2166878920:Fixnum`
```

I'm not even sure if this is the way Mailboxer Notifications are used. I've had a very difficult time finding info on them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to get your unread notifications

```
current_user.mailbox.notifications(:read => false)
```

Comment: I know how to get unread notifications. I was trying to find out how to attach an object to a notification. I just ended up using Public Activity for my notification system, which is working well now.

Comment: Ah I see, my bad. I Believe what you are talking about is being discussed over here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914420/adding-belongs-to-relationship-to-ruby-gem-mailboxer

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/blob/master/app/models/mailboxer/notification.rb

Notification.rb provides a polymorphic association for notified object.

```
belongs_to :notified_object, :polymorphic => :true
```

So you need specify notifications as an Association in Object model which you want to pass.
For ex here you can have in Offer.rb

```
has_many :notifications , as: :notified_object.
```