# Add custom attributes in the mailboxer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, mailboxer

I have used mailboxer gem for the messaging between users in my website.

Which is based on spree module.

I want to add the product id with the conversation so user can filter the conversations according to the products.

How can I achieve this?

Here is the code for message_controller file:

```
module Spree
module Admin
    class MessagesController < Spree::BaseController
      before_action :authenticate_spree_user!

     def index
        filtered_messages = Mailboxer::Message.ads_id(params[:ad_id])
     end

      def new
        @chosen_recipient = Spree::User.find_by(id: params[:to].to_i) if params[:to]

      end

      def create
        product_id = params[:product_id]
        recipients = Spree::User.where(id: params['recipients'])
        conversation = current_spree_user.send_message(recipients, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject], params[:product_id]).conversation
        flash[:success] = 'Message has been sent!'
        redirect_to '/admin/conversations'
      end



      private

       def conversation_params
        #params.require(:mailboxer_conversations).permit(:ad_id)
        params.permit(:ad_id)
      end

    end
end
```

end

Comment: There is a [`send_message`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mailboxer/Mailboxer/Models/Messageable#send_message-instance_method) method which accepts attributes. You can modify the body params for custom attributes and extract it before showing to the users. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @arjun I have used the send_message method but not modified the body param. can u please help me how can i modify the body param.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @arjun I have edited my question.

Comment: Maybe this should solve your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914420/adding-belongs-to-relationship-to-ruby-gem-mailboxer

Comment: Let me know if it helps.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you so much.